# Can't append variable but can console log it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've struggled with this problem for a while but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to loop through the JSON object and append the data for each array to a div in my index.php. But it's not working somehow I can however `console.log` the data but not append it.

```
var result;
getData();

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'api/api.php',
        data: {
            'information' : 'info'
        },
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        },
        dataType: 'HTML'
    });

    result = $.parseJSON(result);
    //console.log(result[1].naam);
}

function dumpData(){
    console.log(test);
    for(var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
        console.log(result[i].naam);
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(result[i].id),
            $('<td>').text(result[i].naam),
            $('<td>').text(result[i].brouwer)
        ).appendTo('#test');
    }
}

console.log('Loaded data.');
dumpData();
console.log('Dumped data.');
```

Index.php:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/Database.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
```

**UPDATE:**
dataType was meant to be JSON  instead of HTML this was the problem.

Comment: I don't get it .. When does the error show ? When you get the data ? When you dump them ? I also don't see any `<tr>` in your Index.php that could be appended with your code

Comment: @mplungjan I reopened it as OP is using `async: false`, so technically it should work.

Comment: Well spotted that it was async:false

Comment: All those functions are getting done when the page loads. There is no error shown in the console. I dump them in the function dumpData() and it's called at the end of the file. There is no <tr>'s in the code because they are being made in the for loop @tektiv, I have litterly no clue why its not working :/

Comment: @ThomH technically what you have should work fine, check the console for errors. That being said, using `async: false` is considered extremely bad practice. You should instead remove that property and call `dumpData()` from within the `success` handler of `$.ajax`, passing the `result` as a parameter.

Comment: Also note that you're attempting to append a `tr` to a `div`, which is not going to work very well

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the quick response I've tried what you said but it's giving some errors now http://prntscr.com/b68r4y , also if I use .length it returns 194304 instead of 750 arrays

Comment: You also loop once too many with your `<=` - see my answer for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to do what you are trying is to not use async:false, to append in the success of the call and to append the rows to a table.

You also loop once too many with the `<=`

Also your code relies on the result to be correct JSON and not HTML as in

```js
var result = [ 
  { "id":"0", "naam":"Thom", "brouwer":"Heineken" },
  { "id":"1", "naam":"Bram", "brouwer":"Amstel" },
  { "id":"2", "naam":"Aad", "brouwer":"Grolsch" } // no comma on the last
  ];


function dumpData(result){
    console.log(result);
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(result[i].id),
            $('<td>').text(result[i].naam),
            $('<td>').text(result[i].brouwer)
        ).appendTo('#test');
    }
}

console.log('Loaded data.');
dumpData(result);
console.log('Dumped data.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="test"></tbody>
</table>
```

I would personally code the Ajax as

```
function getData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'api/api.php',
    data: {
        'information' : 'info'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        dumpData(data)
    },
    dataType: 'JSON'
  });
}
```

and have

```
function dumpData(data){
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that I had dataType on 'HTML' in the ajax call instead of JSON

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting HTML directly in loop to div test.

```
$('#test').html('<tr><td>'"+ result[i].id +"'</td><td>'"+ result[i].naam +"'</td><td>'"+ result[i].brouwer +"'</td></tr>');
```

instead of

```
$('<tr>').append(
   $('<td>').text(result[i].id),
   $('<td>').text(result[i].naam),
   $('<td>').text(result[i].brouwer)
).appendTo('#test');
```